# Codeigniter url not working with subdomain

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have created an application using Codeigniter and I have hosted it on to a subdomain, I have also used an htaccess file to redirect and I put the htaccess file in the same folder as the system and application folder, but I cannot access the site, I am sure I am doing something wrong but I do not know what it is. when I access the website it says page not found

My config

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.favouritememories.abovetheblues.co.uk/';
```

htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    ### Canonicalize codeigniter URLs

    # If your default controller is something other than
    # "welcome" you should probably change this
    RewriteRule ^(favoriteMemories(/index)?|index(\.php)?)/?$ / [L,R=301]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/index/?$ $1 [L,R=301]

    # Removes trailing slashes (prevents SEO duplicate content issues)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,R=301]

    # Enforce www
    # If you have subdomains, you can add them to
    # the list using the "|" (OR) regex operator
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|favouritememories.abovetheblues) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.abovetheblues.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]

    # Enforce NO www
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.tld/$1 [L,R=301]

    ###

    # Removes access to the system folder by users.
    # Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    # previously this would not have been possible.
    # 'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

    # Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    # such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    # request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>

    # Without mod_rewrite, route 404's to the front controller
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

</IfModule>
```

First few lines of my config

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Base Site URL
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| URL to your CodeIgniter root. Typically this will be your base URL,
| WITH a trailing slash:
|
|   http://example.com/
|
| If this is not set then CodeIgniter will guess the protocol, domain and
| path to your installation.
|
*/
$config['base_url'] = 'http://favouritememories.abovetheblues.co.uk/';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Index File
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Typically this will be your index.php file, unless you've renamed it to
| something else. If you are using mod_rewrite to remove the page set this
| variable so that it is blank.
|
*/
$config['index_page'] = '';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| URI PROTOCOL
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This item determines which server global should be used to retrieve the
| URI string.  The default setting of 'AUTO' works for most servers.
| If your links do not seem to work, try one of the other delicious flavors:
|
| 'AUTO'            Default - auto detects
| 'PATH_INFO'       Uses the PATH_INFO
| 'QUERY_STRING'    Uses the QUERY_STRING
| 'REQUEST_URI'     Uses the REQUEST_URI
| 'ORIG_PATH_INFO'  Uses the ORIG_PATH_INFO
|
*/
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| URL suffix
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option allows you to add a suffix to all URLs generated by CodeIgniter.
| For more information please see the user guide:
|
| http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
*/

$config['url_suffix'] = '';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Language
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This determines which set of language files should be used. Make sure
| there is an available translation if you intend to use something other
| than english.
|
*/
$config['language'] = 'english';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Character Set
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This determines which character set is used by default in various methods
| that require a character set to be provided.
|
*/
$config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';
```

Comment: I faced this problem. I got frustrated .. all htaccess and code are working great but when using subdomain on different server..it not worked! The solution is to enable mod_rewrite on you apache setting and solve my problem!

Comment: Having a similar issue, maybe someone can help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68197936/copy-of-codeigniter-project-does-not-work-on-the-same-server-but-on-a-subdomain

Answer (score 2):

Your `.htaccess` file looks good, please open up this file `application/config/config.php`

and search for `$config['base_url'] = 'http://subdomain.domain.com';` and fill the **right** information.

**note** your `.htaccess` file should be in root folder (aside with `application` and `system` folder)

My own `.htaccess` (exact same situation as yours) looks alike

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

and first few lines `config.php`

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');


//$config['base_url']   = 'http://localhost/bz'; //development
$config['base_url'] = 'http://bz.real-hosting.ufo';  //real dope

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Index File
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Typically this will be your index.php file, unless you've renamed it to
| something else. If you are using mod_rewrite to remove the page set this
| variable so that it is blank.
|
*/
$config['index_page'] = '';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| URI PROTOCOL
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This item determines which server global should be used to retrieve the
| URI string.  The default setting of 'AUTO' works for most servers.
| If your links do not seem to work, try one of the other delicious flavors:
|
| 'AUTO'            Default - auto detects
| 'PATH_INFO'       Uses the PATH_INFO
| 'QUERY_STRING'    Uses the QUERY_STRING
| 'REQUEST_URI'     Uses the REQUEST_URI
| 'ORIG_PATH_INFO'  Uses the ORIG_PATH_INFO
|
*/
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

Comment: This is what my config file looks like

Comment: please try following `$config['base_url'] = 'http://favouritememories.abovetheblues.co.uk/';`

Comment: please also make this edit to config.php file `$config['index_page'] = '';`

Comment: now please go to other folders (inside `./application/` and remove `.htaccess` file) (better yet, dont remove it edit it and put this inside `Deny from all`) Keep in mind there must be one .htaccess file in root directory.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42962/discussion-between-kyslik-and-omade)